# What happens when 2 transactions update record and one rolls back?

Tags: database, transactions, logfile

T : Transaction T
U : Transaction U

**Scenario:** T deletes a record from a block. U inserts a record into the block and the slot where the previously deleted record is picked to hold the new record. T now rolls back.

**Questions:**

1. Are the old values of deleted records saved in the log file
2. If yes, for this scenario, what actually happens?

Comment: Which db vendor and version?  From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017  ,  BEGIN TRANSACTION starts a local transaction for the connection issuing the statement. Depending on the current transaction isolation level settings, many resources acquired to support the Transact-SQL statements issued by the connection are locked by the transaction until it is completed with either a COMMIT TRANSACTION or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement.  Which sez to me, U transaction could not begin.